# Change the color of numberings in inline itemization

Tags: lists, color, paralist

```
 \begin{inparaenum}[1)]
    \item  number one item
    \item  number two item
    \item  number three item
 \end{inparaenum}
```

Is it possible to change the color of the number, When I use \textcolor{red}{1)} it is showing red color but it stopped itemizing. So instead of 1,2 3 I just got 1,1,1, for all the items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\begin{inparaenum}[\color{red} 1)]
    \item  number one item
    \item  number two item
    \item  number three item
 \end{inparaenum}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) which can now do this as well.  In the latest release, the `[inline]` package options defines three inline lists:  `enumerate*`, `itemize*`, and `description*`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate*}[\begingroup\color{red} 1)\endgroup]
    \item  number one item
    \item  number two item
    \item  number three item
 \end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

I used the `[shortlabels]` package option above to simplify the comparison, but `enumitem` really offers a lot more flexibility.   Related questions:

1. [What are the differences between using paralist vs. enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18411/what-are-the-differences-between-using-paralist-vs-enumitem)
2. [Suggestions for transitioning from paralist to enumitem package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/suggestions-for-transitioning-from-paralist-to-enumitem-package)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem and found a workaround:

**MY PROBLEM** was that one cannot color only the first number of a `enumitem` `enumerate` list. That is

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \textcolor{red}{\item first}
    \item second
\end{enumerate}
```

won't work.

My workaround is to *split the list in 2 sublists* using `resume`, i.e.

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textcolor{red}{\arabic*.}]
    \item this is a red number one
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textcolor{black}{\arabic*.},resume*]
    \item this is a black number two
\end{enumerate}
```