# What are the differences between using paralist vs. enumitem

Tags: packages, lists, enumitem, paralist

I am looking for advice on which of these packages to use? Under what circumstances would `paralist` be preferred over `enumitem`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I normaly use `enumitem` as a standard package in my documents. A quick comparison of the two in the following list: (e)-enumitem and (p)-paralist

- In paragraph enumeration  (p)
- Enumeration as paragraph  (p)
- Resume enumeration         (e)
- Set defaults                    (e,p)
- Compact lists                  (e,p)
- Keyvalue args                 (e)
- Change labels                  (e,p)
- Change refs                    (e)
- Legal or stacked list type labels   (e,p)
- Trivlist correction            (e)

`Enumitem` is the more advanced package, for example the trivlist correction leaves the spacing environmens such as quote unchanged and the keyvalue arguments makes on the fly changes to the lables and refs easy. A big plus point is also the resuming of enumerate counters after a break.

The strong point of `paralist` is the in-paragraph enumerations, but it is something I do not use often.

Comment: Nice summary. There is an alpha release (v3.0) of `enumitem` which has in-paragraph list support. It hasn't been released officially, though.

Comment: enumitem 3.0 is now on ctan

Comment: The `enumitem` option is called `inline`

Answer (score 22):

`paralist` also provides "compact" variants of the standard lists.  You can emulate them in `enumitem` using the following:

```
\newlist{compactitem}{itemize}{3}
\setlist[compactitem]{topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt}
\setlist[compactitem,1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[compactitem,2]{label=---}
\setlist[compactitem,3]{label=*}

\newlist{compactdesc}{description}{3}
\setlist[compactdesc]{topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt}

\newlist{compactenum}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[compactenum]{topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt}
\setlist[compactenum,1]{label=\arabic*}
\setlist[compactenum,2]{label=\alph*}
\setlist[compactenum,3]{label=\roman*}
```

Edit: Thanks to @Alan for pointing out my misreading.  `enumitem` permits nesting lists up to **6** deep, at least for newly created enumerate-like lists.  (That removes any quibble I had about `enumitem` versus native lists, since I think native lists don't nest by default that deep :-p)

I haven't figured out `enumitem` equivalents for the in-paragraph lists, yet, but as another answer points out, such support is being added to enumitem v3.0.

Comment: The `enumitem` package allows you to construct lists of arbitrary depth: `\newlist{<listname>}{<type>}{<maxdepth>}`.

Comment: At least in v2.1, there's a check on maxdepth, though: `\ifnum#1>#3\relax \@toodeep \else ... \fi`, where #3 is the maxdepth.  And there's a comment saying that for itemize and enumerate, #3 is `\thr@@`.  I _thought_ that meant I'd get stopped after nesting 3 deep...but maybe I'm misreading macro parameters again...

Comment: Well for newly created enumerate lists in v.2.2, the limit seems to be 6 (7 gives an error, so it's not *quite* arbitrary depth). I won't post the code in the comment. :-)  BTW, if you add @Alan to your comment I'll be alerted to it.

Comment: Here I found the solution to a problem I experienced in beamer. Compactitem from paralist did not show the bullets.