# Resuming a list started within a minipage

Tags: lists, enumerate, minipage, enumitem

I have a minipage with a figure, and I want part (a) to be on the right of this figure (so part (a) is in a 2nd minipage), and the remaining parts (b), (c), etc to be below.  The insights provided in [What are the differences between using paralist vs. enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18411/what-are-the-differences-between-using-paralist-vs-enumitem) indicate that `enumitem` is the way to go.

My first thought was to begin the enumerate within the 2nd minipage, and attempt to resume this list outside of this minipage as documented in [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list).  When I attempt to use the `resume*` option provided by the `enumitem` package, this option seems to be ignored, and the text "**resume,,**" is added to the output.

I then thought about starting the `\begin{enumerate}` outside of the first minipage, and having the first `\item` within the 2nd minipage. Surprisingly this almost works, except that it has a problem if I uncomment the `\begin{center}`, `\end{center}` lines.  This is the second part below.  But since this results in a syntax error (and even *seems* wrong to me) with the uncommented lines to me indicates that this is not proper usage.

The [output of this can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO4gr.png).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \fbox{Figure here.}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item One
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
Now this should be part (b), and "resume" should not be printed here:

\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}

\hrule% Alternate attempt, but "feels" wrong...

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]% Move enumerate outside of minipage
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    %\begin{center}% "Missing item" if this is uncommented
        \fbox{Figure here.}
    %\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  \item One
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
Now this should be part (b), and "resume" should not be printed here:

  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

So, how do I properly do this (and still be able to use the `center` environment).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that enumitem forgets the setting for `resume*` if the `enumerate` is in a minipage.

I'd use a more enumitem-like syntax:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \fbox{Figure here.}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item One
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
    \end{itemize}
  \global\chardef\keepnumber=\value{enumi}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
Now this should be part (b), and "resume" should not be printed here:

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \setcounter{enumi}{\keepnumber}
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}
```

Unfortunately, the `start=` option seems to like only explicit numbers. Of course this complicated method is necessary only if you don't want to do the bookkeeping yourself.

Answer (score 7):

This problem has now been solved in version 3.0 of the `enumitem` package via the *Series* capabilities, which will store the properties of a list globally.

The MWE of the OP would become:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \fbox{Figure here.}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[(1),series=mylist] % Add series name to the first list
  \item One
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
Now this should be part (b), and "resume" should not be printed here:

\begin{enumerate}[resume*=mylist] % use `resume*` to resume the previous named list with formatting
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This would correctly give:

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

The group added by the `minipage` hinders the second `enumerate` to remember the settings of the previous one. If you add an `enumerate` environment before all that it actually resumes this one instead. The '`resume,,`' added seems to be a bug caused by using the `resume*` option with no previous `enumerate` (in the same scope).

In your specific case I would just manually reset the formatting options (`(a)`) and set the beginning of the enumeration (`start=2`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \fbox{Figure here.}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item One
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}[(a),start=2]
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg: I like the simplicity of Martin's solution, but am going to accept egreg as that is more automated (even thought I dislike adding extra code) in that it will automatically adjust the counters if more list items are added later.