# Enumeration in the `parcolumns` environment

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, parcolumns

I am encountering a problem in the `parcolumns` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}


\begin{parcolumns}[rulebetween=false]{2}
\colchunk[1]{\textbf{Logical properties of \emph{before}}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item $(p \vee q)$B$r \longleftrightarrow (p\text{B}r \vee q\text{B}r)$
\item $p$B$(q  \vee r) \longleftrightarrow (p\text{B}q \wedge p\text{B}r)$ 
\item $p$B$q   \longrightarrow p$
\end{enumerate}}
\colchunk[2]{\textbf{Logical properties of \emph{before}}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item $(p \vee q)$A$r \longleftrightarrow (p\text{A}r \vee q\text{A}r)$
\item $p$A$(q  \vee r) \longleftrightarrow (p\text{A}q \vee p\text{A}r)$
\item $p$A$q   \longrightarrow p$
\item $p$A$q   \longrightarrow q$
\end{enumerate}}
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

I want the numbering to continue and not to be the same on the two lists. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `resume*=` and define a name for the `series`:

[image]

### References:

- [Resuming a list started within a minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21596/resuming-a-list-started-within-a-minipage)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}


\begin{parcolumns}[rulebetween=false]{2}
\colchunk[1]{\textbf{Logical properties of \emph{before}}
\begin{enumerate}[series=X]
\item $(p \vee q)$B$r \longleftrightarrow (p\text{B}r \vee q\text{B}r)$
\item $p$B$(q  \vee r) \longleftrightarrow (p\text{B}q \wedge p\text{B}r)$ 
\item $p$B$q   \longrightarrow p$
\end{enumerate}}
\colchunk[2]{\textbf{Logical properties of \emph{before}}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=X]
\item $(p \vee q)$A$r \longleftrightarrow (p\text{A}r \vee q\text{A}r)$
\item $p$A$(q  \vee r) \longleftrightarrow (p\text{A}q \vee p\text{A}r)$
\item $p$A$q   \longrightarrow p$
\item $p$A$q   \longrightarrow q$
\end{enumerate}}
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```