# Option [(a)] to get alphabet numbering when applied to enumerate doesn't work

Tags: lists, enumerate

According to this popular guide http://texblog.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/lists-enumerate-itemize-description-and-how-to-change-them/, I should be able to apply an option `[(a)]` to get small case alphabet numbering.  As it is below, I cannot:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\date{}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item {\bf \ce{CH3Br + KOH -> CH3OH + KBr}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's
wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX
Companion for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help.  ...    

                                                   l.22 \item {
            \bf \ce{CH3Br + KOH -> CH3OH + KBr}} ?
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This feature isn't part of 'standard' LaTeX, but is provided by the enumerate package.

You need to `\usepackage{enumerate}`.

Answer (score 9):

You should consider using `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` as I belive that that is a newer package. See [What are the differences between using paralist vs. enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18411/what-are-the-differences-between-using-paralist-vs-enumitem) for a comparison of the `paralist` and `enumitem`

Comment: The `enumitem` package offers substantially more flexibility that the `enumerate` package, but for simple things like changing the labels, the `enumerate` package does a fine job as well.