# Redefining \enumerate using \let - why does it behave this way and what can I do to bypass it?

Tags: macros, lists, environments, enumerate

The following code produces a result, that I find quite strange:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\origenumerate\enumerate
\renewenvironment{enumerate}{\begin{origenumerate}}{\end{origenumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item{First}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item{First-1}
    \item{First-2}
\end{enumerate}
\item{Second}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Actual result:

```
    1. First
        (a) First-1
    (b) First-2
2. Second
```

Expected result (as without third line in code):

```
    1. First
        (a) First-1
        (b) First-2
    2. Second
```

Why is this so? How can I redefine \enurate to use custom \parskip and \itemsep without getting this kind of (bad) jokes?

edit: I am using pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)

Comment: There's no need to use braces around each item: you can use `\item First` instead of `\item{First}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually in these cases you need to use the lower-level internal commands for the environment, and also remember about the `\end...` one. Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\origenumerate\enumerate
\let\origendenumerate\endenumerate
\renewenvironment{enumerate}{\origenumerate}{\origendenumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item{First}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item{First-1}
    \item{First-2}
\end{enumerate}
\item{Second}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You were 5sec faster :-)

Comment: @Andres: See also my answer to [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way/14684#14684) for an explanation between the higher and lower level form.

Comment: 8sec faster, in my case ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is change the spacing, a package like [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) is probably safer than this kind of low level hacking.

Comment: `\enumitem` is probably the one to use. See [this for a comparrison between paralist and enumitem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18411/what-are-the-differences-between-using-paralist-vs-enumitem)