# Coloured numbering in a list?

Tags: lists, color, enumerate, enumitem

Is there a way to obtain coloured numbering in an `enumerate` list?

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item Second
\item Third
\end{enumerate}
```

I'd like the 1, 2, 3 to be in blue. I thought this should be simple, but could find nothing on this. I also tried with

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

and

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={\color{blue}}]
```

but this simply generated a list with no numbering.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\color{blue}\theenumi]
 %  \begin{enumerate}[\color{blue} 1]% Alternative
\item First
\item Second
\item Third
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine – my problem was I was not including `xcolor'.

Comment: @Herbert: I belive that the alternative commented out requires the `\usepackage [shortlabels]{enumitem}`.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\begingroup\color{blue} 1)\endgroup]
     \item First
     \item Second
     \item Third
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textcolor{blue}{\arabic*}]
    \item  number one item
    \item  number two item
    \item  number three item
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{document}
```

This question [Change the color of numberings in inline itemization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8134/change-the-color-of-numberings-in-inline-itemization) is also helpful, even though it refers to an inline list.

Comment: – this only worked for me if I dropped the `inline' element.

Comment: The `[inline]` package option only provides additional `*` environments that are inline lists. The above example only used the non-star elements so there should not be anything different.