# Changing color of default enumeration

Tags: beamer, lists, color, enumerate

To my surprise, I've had trouble finding red themes, and used the [`beamer` theme matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/) to find `CambridgeUS`.  I've changed the itemized bullets to match, but I can't seem to make the enumerations red.  I tried `\setbeamertemplate{items}[red]` from the `beamer` manual, and I tried `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default, red]` which also didn't work.  It looks like it can be done in each enumerate environment like [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28056/coloured-numbering-in-a-list), but is there a way for me to do it once, in the preamble, without defining a custom command?  I thought this sort of thing would be common.  At the moment my preamble is

```
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
```

Alternatively, if there is another template for enumerate items that uses the default markers and is red, that would work too.

EDIT:

I'm able to change the color of the top level number with `\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=red}`, but they don't all inherit as I would expect when I try `\setbeamercolor{enumerate items}{fg=red}`.

EDIT AGAIN:

It looks like using `\documentclass[red]{beamer}` turns them red (not a great shade or red, but reddish nonetheless).  I read somewhere that doing this is obsolete, so please let me know if there is something more current that I should be using.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `local structure` to cause the colour inheritance:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=darkred}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=darkred}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{A block}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item.
  \begin{itemize}
    \item First subitem.
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First subsubitem.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: i presume your `\setbeamercolor{block title}{}` line just determines the color of the block title...but what is that exactly?  another level of nesting, but with no marker, like a description environment?

Comment: @asia1281 Yes, more or less.  They give some internal structure to a slide.  I use them quite a bit in my own slides. How useful they are obviously depends a lot on the content of your presentations. You can think of it as a title for each itemized list.

Comment: @AlanMunn How to remove the shade in the middle in item projected?

Answer (score 18):

Change the `enumerate subitem` and `enumerate subsubitem` colors also:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\setbeamercolor*{enumerate item}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor*{enumerate subitem}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor*{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=red}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First subitem.
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First subsubitem.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you want to use the same color as the one used in CambridgeUS, you can use `darkred` (defined by the theme) instead of `red`.

[image]

Comment: well yes, I know I can do that, but is there no way to do this so that they inherit/are all changed?  that can't be the modern replacement for `\documentclass[red]{beamer}` can it?