# Itemize dislocated to the left

Tags: itemize

Is it standard for the `itemize` function to be dislocated to the left when you put stuff between the brackets?[image]

Comment: You mean the itemize is aligned to the right?

Comment: Yes. I think you want the `description` environment instead.

Comment: What do you mean by description environment? I guess I wish to indent the items in `itemize` just so you can see the blue texts completely.

Comment: substitute the word `itemize` with `description` and test the result.

Comment: Hum, with the `description` function we solve the problem of the missing "hidden text" but the text alignment gets a bit ugly. I managed to do so by adding `\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1in]`. But this makes it lose its color. I tried this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28056/coloured-numbering-in-a-list, but it isn't working so far.

Comment: Well, I used tho circumvent the problem: either I use a "fake" itemizing environment, where the only item is the real "itemize", or better: I use \item[], and the text highlighted with the color you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe using the enumitem solves the problem, the text in the `description` function is (in the `very very long item`) set underneath the item's title. With `enumitem` the indentation is prettier. (But I can't still work out the coloring...)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1.9in,label=\color{blue}\theenumi]
    \item[Nó Móvel - Agente Externo:] O nó móvel...
    \item[Agente Externo - Agente Nativo:] Registro de COAs.
    \item[Encapsulamento de Datagramas:] Equivalente à etapa 2.
    \item[Desencapsulamento de Datagrama:] Equivalente à etapa 3.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As told you @Paul Gessler ``description` list is intended for such cases. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{description}[long long item]
\item[long item]    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item[item]         text
\item[very very long item]    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    \end{description}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Text in `[...]` at `\begin{description}` (in Beamer) define indentation of text in list. My example show a case when for indentation you don't select widest text of description term.